# autocomplete-python not working for atom python 3.9

Tags: python, atom-editor

i just started learning python and installed autocomplete-python package.
it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acer\.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\completion.py", line 8, in <module>
```

I have tried copying grammar3.6txt and renaming it to grammar3.7txt.
It still says the same error.
Please tell what to do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error that went with that traceback.

Comment: That error message should have at least one more line saying what the actual error is, like `ValueError` or `TypeError` or whatever, and possibly more lines in the traceback. Please [edit] to add the full thing. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: it just says the above error nothing else.

Comment: @Navdeep Well then, we don't have enough info to help. Instead, you could open an issue [on the package](https://github.com/autocomplete-python/autocomplete-python/issues). From a quick look, [this](https://github.com/autocomplete-python/autocomplete-python/issues/453) may be the same issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting this error from "autocomplete-python traceback output:" in atom, be sure to install jedi as per the documentation https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-python

```
pip install jedi
```

Comment: As an addendum, autocomplete-python has been behind on staying up-to-date with the latest jedi versions. You need version `0.17.2` for autocomplete-python to work properly.